# LeetCode 264. ugly number

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Python3

```
while n % 2 == 0:
    n >>= 1
while n % 3 == 0:
    n //= 3
while n % 5 == 0:
    n //= 5
return n == 1
```

This is my code. When I submit this code,the leetcode hint me my code Time Limit Exceeded.

Python3

```
while n:
   if n % 2 == 0:
       n >>= 1
   elif n % 3 == 0:
       n //= 3
   elif n % 5 == 0:
       n //= 5
   else:
       break
return n == 1
```

But when I submit my code like this, can complete detection.Why?

Comment: Problem description should be inside  the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent chance Leetcode runs your algorithm with the initial value `0`.

Your original code enters an infinite loop, while the modified version won't go into the loop when `n == 0`.

For all other inputs, the performance of both should be essentially the same.